# dot sourcing doesn't work within shell script

Tags: shell-script, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL and try to automate a build process via shell script. The process starts with sourcing some exported variables from a file, say `/asdf/2.3.4./test`, containing a single line of exports:

```
export VAR1="test"
```

Now I try to source this from a shell script `build_lib.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /asdf/2.3.4/test
```

Executing this results in an error:

```
me@here:path/to/build$ ./build_lib.sh
: not found.sh: 2:
./build_lib.sh: 3: .: Can't open /asdf/2.3.4/test
```

However, sourcing from the shell directly works just fine:

```
me@here:path/to/build$ env | grep VAR1
me@here:path/to/build$ . /asdf/2.3.4/test
me@here:path/to/build$ env | grep VAR1
VAR1=test
me@here:path/to/build$
```

What am I doing wrong with the script?

Comment: Have you written your script(s) on Windows? Consider converting them from DOS to Unix text file format using `dos2unix`.

Comment: @Kusalananda That was indeed what caused the issue. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of a similar question.  The question is not _identical_, but the errors are similar (`not found` vs. `No such file or directory`) and _the cause of the errors are the same_ (DOS text file).